# Still Photo Rendering in Premiere Pro CC 2015 is Yellowy After Export

Tags: premiere

So I start with a perfectly good JPG still set in the timeline 4 second long duration cross dissolve to another photo.  Not all photos change color after rendering.  And this only just stated happening.  Now I can't get it to go away.  Have tried several different export types (H264, Wide DVD, MP4, etc.) but they all look the same.  Does anyone have any suggestions.

[image: Bad Render Output]
[image: Good Photo]

Comment: Did any bit depth settings change on the output?  That is extremely odd behavior.

Comment: Put the image into a new sequence with no plugins, effects or anything else... Do you still get the same issue?  This will at least narrow down the issue..

Comment: Also share your sequence settings and export settings as a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try re-saving the image to different formats. Often this will do the trick.